# Don't update route component when redux state changes

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router-dom

How to don't update component rendered by Route if something in redux changed? Added some examples of routing, component which lazy imported has redux store connection.

```
const ROUTES_OPTIONS = [
  {
    path: `${PATH_TO_SMART_ACCESS}${PATH_TO_SMART_ACCESS_VIEW}/options`,
    Component: lazy(() => import("./SmartAccessActionsOptions")),
    exact: false
  },
  {
    path: `${PATH_TO_SMART_ACCESS}${PATH_TO_SMART_ACCESS_VIEW}/:id/options/:type?`,
    Component: lazy(() => import("./SmartAccessActionsOptions")),
    exact: false
  }
];

const Routes = () => {
  return (
    <Switch>
      {ROUTES_OPTIONS.map(route => (
        <Route
          key={route.path}
          exact={route.exact}
          render={() => {
            const Component = route.Component;
            return <Component />;
          }}
        />
      ))}
    </Switch>
  );
};
```

Comment: Add some code example

Comment: @Antoni it's question about life cycle... I have Switch, Route and component. When redux state is changes then component inside router unmounts and mounts again, but I don't want that

Comment: if you change the route then the previous component will be unmount automatically you can't anything on that.

Comment: @Ashish I only change the state in redux store. Nothing changes in routes but component unmounts and mounts again

Comment: maybe you are reloading the page, please check.

Comment: @Ashish nothing is reloads. Page is static, but components wrapped in router are re-renders

Comment: can you show your code of router.

Comment: @Ashish added exampl

Comment: is your router component  is connected with redux using connect?

Comment: @Ashish hooks and redux Provider

Comment: if you change the redux state then your component lifecycle methods like componentWillUpdate , componentWillReceiveProps execute, so may be the problem will be here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207349/discussion-between-marty-and-ashish).

Comment: According to the [`react-router-dom` docs](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/render-func), using the `render` prop won't trigger your component to remount. The problem is clearly elsewhere. Please share a [Minimal, Reproducible, and Complete](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your issue.